# Function doesn't return correct value

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am trying to write a Fortran 77 program where a subroutine makes a function call, with the function being provided as an argument (to the subroutine).

The problem I am facing is that function 'bar' doesn't return the correct result. Here is a minimal (not) working example:

```
% cat mwe.f
      real*8 function bar()
      print *,"bar:",bar
      bar = 101.0d00
      print *,"bar:",bar
      end

      subroutine foo(func)
      real*8 rv
      rv = func()
      print *,"rv:",rv
      end

      program tsig
      external bar
      call foo(bar)
      end
% gfortran mwe.f && ./a.out
 bar:   0.0000000000000000
 bar:   101.00000000000000
 rv:   0.0000000000000000
%
```

Comment: Does your default real (as `bar` is implicitly typed in the program and `foo`) correspond to a declaration `real*8`?

Comment: Hm, as far as I can tell default real in my system is real*4. Doesn't 'real*8 function bar' make bar() return a 'real*8' ?

Comment: `real*8` is the return type of `bar` (as declared in that function statement).  However, in the main program and in`foo` there is no such declaration.  So, `func` in `foo` is implicitly typed as default real, which may not be the same thing for you as (non-standard) `real*8`.  Just because `rv` is declared as `real*8` doesn't mean that the function result `func()` is that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was stated in the comments, but perhaps it should be said explicitly, because, you still appear to struggle. Keeping (pseudo) Fortran 77 you must do

```
  subroutine foo(func)
    real*8 rv
    real*8 func
    rv = func()
    print *,"rv:",rv
  end
```

The reason is that the type of `func` is assumed to be implicitly `real` inside `foo`. You must declare it explicitly if it returns some other type.

I **strongly** recommend to place `implicit none` at the start of each program and subroutine. It isn't part of Fortran 77 standard, but neither is `real*8`. Both are just common extensions. `implicit none` is standard in Fortran 90, `real*8` is not standard Fortran at all.

Answer (score 0):

code: simple.f

```
function bar()
  real*8 :: bar
  print *,"bar:",bar
  bar = 101.0d00
  print *,"bar:",bar
  return
end function bar

subroutine foo(func)
    interface
      function func()
        real*8 :: func
      end function func
    end interface
    real*8 rv
    rv = func()
    print *,"rv:",rv
end subroutine foo

program tsig
  external bar
  call foo(bar)
end
```

result:

```
./a.out
 bar:   2.1219959811805460E-314
 bar:   101.00000000000000
 rv:   101.00000000000000
```

Comment: Any comments? Explanation? While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this isn't Fortran 77.  Although there are few good reasons to really write such a thing now, the question does explicitly state that requirement.

Comment: You have to add interface inside subroutine to make func visible to your calling routine. Unfortunately, It's not enough to pass it as argument.

Comment: Write it into your answer, not in the comments, which may be deleted at any time.

Comment: The code seems to work fine. Are 'interface' and :: Fortran 77 ? gfortran compiles it fine; I'm not sure how to check if Fortran 77 is assumed by default in the compiler. UPDATE: I installed 'fort77' and it can't compile this source.